# How to use theme Selected style for Component in ListCellRenderer if isSelected

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a custom `ListCellRenderer` in which I would like to have the currently selected item highlighted with a background gradient.

It seems like I should be able to define the `Selected` style for the rendered component in the Codenameone Designer under theme and set that UIID for the component to achieve this.

I can't figure out how to pass the selected state of the list item to the Label component being rendered though, so I resort to changing the style manually as you can see in my code below. Can I accomplish the same behaviour with my theme `Resources` somehow?

```
public class PlanetListRenderer extends Container implements ListCellRenderer<Hashtable<String, String>> {
    private Label planetLabel = new Label();
    private Resources theme;

    public PlanetListRenderer(Resources theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
        BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(bl);

        planetLabel.setUIID("PlanetListItem");
        planetLabel.setTextPosition(Label.BOTTOM);
        addComponent(planetLabel);
    }

    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        return planetLabel;
    }
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list,
            Hashtable<String, String> value, int index, boolean isSelected) {

        planetLabel.setIcon(theme.getImage("icon" + value.get("value") + ".png"));
        planetLabel.setText(value.get("value"));

        if ( isSelected ) {
            planetLabel.getStyle().setBackgroundGradientStartColor(255255255);
            planetLabel.getStyle().setBackgroundGradientRelativeY(0.2f);
            planetLabel.getStyle().setBackgroundGradientRelativeSize(1.0f);
            planetLabel.getStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_RADIAL);
        } else {
            planetLabel.getStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_NONE);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added Java tag for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a ListCellRenderer which changes the selected item. Not sure if it does what you're looking for, but you can see it for real from Google Play (or App Store) by searching for "Torquepower Diesel Cummins Engine" app. When you select any list item you'll see the backgound change.

```
public class FaultCodesListCellRenderer extends Container implements ListCellRenderer {

Label focus;
Label code;
Label effect;
Image warning;
Image emergency;

public FaultCodesListCellRenderer(Resources res) {

    // get images for warning lights
    emergency = res.getImage("emergency.png");
    warning = res.getImage("warning.png");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setUIID("Underline");

    code = new Label();
    code.setUIID("BoldLabel");
    code.setTextPosition(RIGHT);
    code.getStyle().setMargin(Component.RIGHT, 6);

    effect = new Label();
    effect.setTickerEnabled(false);

    addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, code);
    addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, effect);

    int h = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(8, false);
    setPreferredH(code.getPreferredH() < h ? h : code.getPreferredH());

    focus = new Label("");
    focus.setUIID("UnderlineSelected");

}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {

    Diagnostic diagnostic = (Diagnostic) value;

    if (diagnostic.light.equals("R")) {
        code.setIcon(emergency);
    } else {
        code.setIcon(warning);
    }
    code.setText(diagnostic.code);
    effect.setText(diagnostic.effect);

    return this;
}

public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
    return focus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using background images/borders instead of gradients which aren't as performant.

By default touch UI's don't show selection permanently. If you use `getAllStyles` instead of `getStyle` e.g.:

```
Form hi = new Form("Renderer Demo", new BorderLayout());
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<>();
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 100 ; iter++) {
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("key1", "Data " + iter);
    data.put("key2", "Different Data " + iter);
    al.add(data);
}
DefaultListModel<Map<String, String>> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>(al);
List<Map<String, String>> l = new List<>(listModel);
l.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
    private Container           container;
    private Label                   cover;
    private TextArea             item;

    {
        item = new TextArea(2, 80);
        cover = new Label();
        container = BorderLayout.center(item).add(BorderLayout.EAST, cover);
        container.setCellRenderer(true);
        cover.setCellRenderer(true);
        item.setCellRenderer(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
        Map<String, String> val = (Map<String, String>)value;
        item.setText(val.get("key1"));
        cover.setText(val.get("key2"));

        Style itemStyle = item.getAllStyles();
        Style coverStyle = cover.getAllStyles();
        Style containerStyle = container.getAllStyles();

        itemStyle.setBgTransparency(255);
        coverStyle.setBgTransparency(255);
        containerStyle.setBgTransparency(255);

        if (isSelected) {
            itemStyle.setFgColor(0xff0000);
            itemStyle.setBgColor(0x000000);
            coverStyle.setBgColor(0xff0000);
            containerStyle.setBgColor(0x000000);
        } else {
            itemStyle.setFgColor(0x000000);
            itemStyle.setBgColor(0xffffff);
            coverStyle.setBgColor(0x000000);
            containerStyle.setBgColor(0xffffff);
        }

        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        return null;
    }
});
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, l);
hi.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however my question is, can I accomplish this same behaviour with my theme Resources?  So, in your example, can I set a UIID on "item" with the normal colors under Unselected style tab and the selected colors under Selected style tab and have that applied in the Renderer?

Comment: Yes. Just use setUIID. You can also return two different component instances E.g. have a component instance for selected and a different one for unselected. Personally I wouldn't go this way... I would use radio buttons (with `setToggleButton(true)`) within a Box Y container. List is generally awkward for many advanced usages.